# Add time in django Models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I tried subtracting two times in models.py but I got error. Here is my model That I have been working.

```
class Schedule(BaseModel):
    bus_company_route = models.ForeignKey(BusCompanyRoute, on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    travel_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

and `BusCompanyRoute` have journey length.

```
class BusCompanyRoute(BaseModel):
    journey_length = models.TimeField(null=True)
```

Now I tried adding these times in using `@property`  decorator in following way

```
@property
def journey_end_time(self):
    return self.travel_date_time.time()+self.bus_company_route.journey_length
```

but end up getting following error warning as:
`Class 'time' does not define '__add__', so the '+' operator cannot be used on its instances` 
How can I solve it?

Comment: Use a `DurationField` for storing the duration of the journey not a `TimeField`, this will give you a `timedelta` that you can add or subtract from a `datetime` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield

Comment: thank you ! Solved  changed time field to duration field `journey_length = models.DurationField(null=True)`  you may provided answer for acceptance

Comment: Happy to have helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) is more appropriate for storing the duration of a journey not a `TimeField`, this will give you a timedelta that you can add or subtract from a datetime whereas a `TimeField` just gives a static time of day

```
class BusCompanyRoute(BaseModel):
    journey_length = models.DurationField(null=True)
```